# Why Hibernation does not work on my Vista64 Desktop?

Tags: windows-vista, hibernate

I have an custom-made personal *Desktop* (*not* laptop) Vista64 Ultimate - up-to-date in term of Windows updates and drivers, Asus Rampage Formula, 8Go RAM and 6 hard-drives (2To), which refuses to go to Hibernation.
It fades to black screen, then, 3 seconds later, the Windows desktop reappear (without me touching anything).

- The option "hibernation" is there (I followed the [Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B929658&x=14&y=13) to enable it),
- I disabled anything that might "wake up" the computer (as listed [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaperformance/thread/e8892bea-bc57-42ba-9832-336d8e8f08aa))
- I tweaked the power options in order to allow hibernation even if sharing files
- I do not see anything suspicious in the event viewer.
- I have enough disk space on my `C:\`

Yet it refuses to go into hibernation mode
(I am not speaking about an issue for *exiting* hibernation mode here: I do not manage to even *enter* in that mode!).
Any other suggestions besides the ones listed here?

Answer (score 3):

Two things I can think of:

- Make sure your BIOS has ACPI setup correctly. I guess it is but it is good to check.
- I know Windows Media Centre exhibits this kind of behaviour if it is recording a show. There are also “Multimedia Settings” as part of the advanced power plans that can prevent your computer from sleeping if you’re sharing music. Maybe you’re running other software which is preventing Windows from sleeping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (+1). I will check on the ACPI front. Regarding the advanced power options, I did what you recommend (that is what I meant by "I tweaked the power options in order to allow hibernation even if sharing files"). I will try to enter hibernate mode with a minimal set of programs running.

Answer (score 1):

Did you plug in your laptop after it turned off? On my pc that will sometimes wake it back up. You could plug it in before you hibernate it.