# Computer wakes up from standby when mouse moved

Tags: suspend

I have an Asus A8N-SLI motherboard in my media HTPC, running Windows XP. Normally it remains in sleep mode but when the USB (wireless) mouse is even slightly jogged it wakes up which means it often wakes up when it is not needed... Is there a way to make it so that the computer only wakes up when a key is pressed or a mouse button is clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/226/desktop-reboots-itself-on-sleep-or-hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit the win+r (windows key and then "r"), enter devmgmt.msc in the dialog box. Find "Mice and other pointing devices" and expand the item. Double click on your mouse and in the window that pops up click the "power management" tab. Finally untick "Allow this device to wake the computer" and click OK.

Comment: I wonder does this affects to BOIS?

Comment: @RecNes -- Only if you're already lost in the woods.

Comment: Oh my, it took me 1 year to realize the computer wakes up because of my mouse.... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn this feature off in BIOS settings (I guess it's in "Power Management" menu). You can change If motherboards bios supoorts "wake on keypress" or "wake on mouse click" In most cases you can reach bios settings while boot up by pressing  "Del(ete)" key on the keyboard.

Use the motherboard guide at Asus web site...