# How do I tell if my computer supports hibernation?

Tags: windows-vista, power-management, hibernate, desktop-computer, hybrid-sleep

In Windows Vista, there is regular Hibernation as well as a Hybrid Sleep mode. These features can be found and enabled in the Power Options dialog (advanced settings). For some reason, I don't have these options available on my desktop computer.

This is what my dialog box looks like:

[image: power options dialog1]

Note that the options `Allow hybrid sleep` as well as `Hibernate after` are missing under the Sleep section.

How do I tell if this is related to my hardware and the device drivers? What can I do about it?

**Update:**

After running `powercfg /hibernation on` I now have the Hybrid Sleep and Hibernation options.

[image: power options dialog2]

Comment: have you tried **POWERCFG /HIBERNATE ON** to enable Hibernation?

Comment: No, I haven't. Because I don't want to enforce hibernation on it if it's not supported by the hardware. Why else would it be missing from the options?... any idea? So I would prefer to know the reason behind it before I start implementing solutions to an unknown problem.

Comment: Microsoft [KB920730](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920730) explains how to enable and disable Hibernation using `powercfg.exe`. I'm supposed to use `powercfg /hibernate on` and `powercfg /hibernate off`. That's fairly simple, but why is the option from the dialog box missing then?...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/142/why-hibernation-does-not-work-on-my-vista64-desktop?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments suggested, hibernation is not hardware specific but rather software specific.

Click your START button and type CMD, Right click on the CMD icon and select `Run as administrator`. Type `POWERCFG /HIBERNATE ON` in the command prompt window and press `enter`.

The nature of hibernation will tell the OS to dump all physical memory onto the hard disk and the OS will check the hibernation file upon power on. During the hibernation, the system is fully powered down and no power draw is occurred.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Will this bring up the options I mentioned in the question?...

Comment: Once it is enabled (and possible a reboot) you should see hibernation in the dropdown of the Power Options.

Comment: Thanks! I now have the Hybrid Sleep and Hibernation options. I have not tested it yet but I'm pretty sure it will work now. It didn't require a reboot.

Comment: I tried it today. It worked like expected. Now I can once again get a power outage and still recover to the last working system state since the RAM data is being dumped to the disk drive (hiberfil.sys). And Hybrid Sleep means I can almost instantly recover the system state since it's being held in RAM as well as HDD, for times when power is not lost. Great! Thanks!

Comment: For the times power is lost, it will restore system state from HDD. This is a bit slower process. And for times power is not lost, it will restore system state from RAM. This is a much quicker process. But it got you covered either way. I'm not interested in using Hibernation only when I have this. Yes, choosing "Sleep" in the menu or pressing the Sleep button on keyboard takes more time than usual, because it has to copy everything from RAM to HDD first before powering off. But that's cool with me.

Comment: For those of you looking for a way to do Hibernation only, make sure you disable the Hybrid Sleep, because otherwise you will not get the option 'Hibernate' in the Windows shut down menu.

Comment: To disable Hybrid Sleep (as sammyg) suggested, go to Power Options: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/turn-off-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-7/

Comment: Also, if you use an SSD, you might want to reconsider using hibernation. Read here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-hibernate-ssd-warranty-purposes/

Answer (score 2):

## How to tell if a computer supports hibernation

To actually test if a computer supports hibernation you can use `powercfg /a`.

The output should tell you if hibernation is supported. This is what I got running this command.

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /a
The following sleep states are available on this system: Standby ( S3 ) Hibernat
e Hybrid Sleep
The following sleep states are not available on this system:
Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

There are also other options you can use. Run `powercfg /?` and see for yourself. For example, running `powercfg /devicequery s4_supported` will list all the devices that support hibernation.

If Hibernation is enabled there should be a `hiberfil.sys` file in system partition root (c:\hiberfil.sys).