# Is Hibernation a hardware specific feature?

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate

I am testing various embedded boards at the moment. I am installing same operating system on these boards and I execute the same script which activates hibernation with `powercfg /hibernate on` and then hibernate the system.

Some boards support the hibernation and system goes into hibernation with `hiberfil.sys` created in the `OS` partition.

Some boards just respond that the system does not support hibernation and never hibernate and no `hiberfil.sys` is created.

This [How do I tell if my computer supports hibernation?](https://superuser.com/questions/605271/how-do-i-tell-if-my-computer-supports-hibernation) question's answer says that hibernation is software specific and not hardware specific.

In my case the only variable is the different boards with different hardwares. The `OS` environment is same and also same script is executed on each board which leads me to think of hibernation as a hardware specific thing.

Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 4):

Noticing this on the [Wikipedia article for hibernation:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing))

> On Windows computers, hibernation is available only if *all* hardware and device drivers are ACPI and plug-and-play–compliant.

If these embedded boards are industrial-type boards that have ISA slots, and you have hardware in them, they may not be PnP-compliant.  There is a PnP standard for ISA, but it's possible newer versions of Windows no longer support this (this was in the early 90's before PCI so ISAPNP is very old)

Comment: The reason is obvious: While all “software state“ (basically a RAM image) is easily restored, hardware state is not. It is up to the drivers to restore the device to the expected state.